# How to connect python code and android app

Tags: python-3.x, react-native, client-server

I have a written a Python code that takes user id and movie name from the user and recommends a list or 10 movie to the user now i have also created an android app using the react native app UI  and i want to take input from the user through the app process the input(user id and Movie name ) and give recommendation (a list of movies) in the app , what should I do to achieve this objective

Comment: Could you add some of the code. Also taking a look here might help: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to run your recommender under [flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/#a-minimal-application).
Then have your mobile app query your recommender service
and display the results.